# How to convert a BasicDBObject to a Mongo Document with the Java Mongo DB driver version 3?

Tags: java, mongodb

In the Java Mongo  DB driver version 3 the API has changed as compared to the version 2.  So a code like this does not compile anymore:

```
BasicDBObject personObj = new BasicDBObject();
collection.insert(personObj)
```

A Collection insert works only with a Mongo Document.

Dealing with the old code I need to ask the question:

What is the best way to convert a BasicDBObject to a Document?

Comment: You may want to see [this](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.0/driver/reference/crud/#codecregistry)

Answer (score 14):

We Can Convert **`BasicDBObject`**
to **`Document`** by the following way

```
public static Document getDocument(DBObject doc)
{
   if(doc == null) return null;
   return new Document(doc.toMap());
}
```

as **`Document`** itself is an implementation of **`Map<String,Object>`**.

and `BasicDBObject` can be too be catch in `DBObject` as `BasicDBObject` is an implementation of `DBObject`.

**@[Black_Rider](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1421328/black-rider) for you too**

Answer (score 9):

I think the easiest thing to do is just change your code to use a Document as opposed to BasicDBObject.

So change

```
BasicDBObject doc = new BasicDBObject("name", "john")
    .append("age", 35)
    .append("kids", kids)
    .append("info", new BasicDBObject("email", "john@mail.com")
    .append("phone", "876-134-667"));
```

To

```
import org.bson.Document;
...
Document doc = new Document("name", "john")
    .append("age", 35)
    .append("kids", kids)
    .append("info", new BasicDBObject("email", "john@mail.com")
    .append("phone", "876-134-667"));
```

and then insert into the collection

```
coll.insertOne(doc);
```

You'll need to change other bits of code to work with MongoDB 3+

MongoDatabase vs. DB
MongoCollection vs DBCollection

Answer (score 3):

The Document is very similar to the BasicDBObject. I am not quite sure what you are referring to as a way to convert BasicDBObjects to Documents, but the Document object provides some very useful methods.

Document.parse(string) will return a Document if you feed it in a JSON string.

Document.append("key", Value) will add to the fields of a Document.

As for the code in your post, this should compile with version 3:

```
Document personObj = new Document();
collection.insertOne(personObj)
```

See

[Java Driver 3.0 Guide](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.0/driver/reference/crud/)

and

[MongoDB Java Driver 3.0 Documentation](https://api.mongodb.org/java/3.0/org/bson/Document.html)

Comment: What is I receive a BasicDBObject from an old method and then I want to insert it?

Comment: You could do Document doc = Document.parse(YourBasicDBObject.toString());

Answer (score 1):

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static Document getDocument(BasicDBObject doc)
{
    if(doc == null) return null;
    Map<String, Object> originalMap = doc.toMap();
    Map<String, Object> resultMap = new HashMap<>(doc.size());  
    for(Entry<String, Object> entry : originalMap.entrySet())
    {
        String key = entry.getKey();
        Object value = entry.getValue();
        if(value == null)
        {
            continue;
        }
        if(value instanceof BasicDBObject)
        {
            value = getDocument((BasicDBObject)value);
        }
        if(value instanceof List<?>)
        {
            List<?> list = (List<?>) value;
            if(list.size() > 0)
            {
                // check instance of first element
                Object firstElement = list.get(0);
                if(firstElement instanceof BasicDBObject)
                {
                    List<Document> resultList = new ArrayList<>(list.size());
                    for(Object listElement : list)
                    {
                        resultList.add(getDocument((BasicDBObject)listElement));
                    }
                    value = resultList;
                }
                else
                {
                    value = list;
                }
            }
        }
        resultMap.put(key, value);
    }
    Document result = new Document(resultMap);
    return result;
}
```